# File manager with media information?

Tags: filemanager, multimedia, media, metadata

So I've been using Ubuntu for like 5 years now but I was really unhelpful when one of my juniors asked me if there was a file manager which for media containing directories can show the media information when the corresponding file is selected, like windows explorer. I never used that kind of sophisticated feature anyway so I thought it might be just a few 'Google' away. But I couldn't find anything. So my question would be if there's any file manager or plugin which can show media metadata into file manager without playing the file. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is "media metadata" ? You mean like the songs in a folder, but you want to see them without going in to the folder ? I've never noticed that in windows,a screenshot would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on a file and choose properties, the last tab in the dialog shows media information. However, there is no way to display this in the sidebar in Nautilus currently, no.

Comment: No. I don't want to use the properties again and again! That's what the question was about!!

Comment: Yes, and the answer is "No, the file manager in Ubuntu does not have this feature, and there is no way to currently display such information in the sidebar."